# Python match filenames and put in a folder

Tags: python

Im trying to match all filenames in a folder, and put them into there own seperate folder with the name of the files.  Heres an example:

```
2015-05-14#6449618a-f819-4d71-83ad-a1e4c2fe9bc1.csv
2015-05-14#6449618a-f819-4d71-83ad-a1e4c2fe9bc1.xml
2015-05-14#6449618a-f819-4d71-83ad-a1e4c2fe9bc1.doc
2015-05-14#6449618a-f819-4d71-83ad-a1e4c2fe9bc1.dox

2015-05-14#7449618a-f819-4d71-83ad-a1e4c2fe9bc1.csv
2015-05-14#7459618a-f819-4d71-83ad-a1e4c2fe9bc1.xml
2015-05-14#7459618a-f819-4d71-83ad-a1e4c2fe9bc1.doc
2015-05-14#7459618a-f819-4d71-83ad-a1e4c2fe9bc1.doc
```

I want to group these files into a folder, with the foldername being

```
2015-05-14#7449618a-f819-4d71-83ad-a1e4c2fe9bc1
2015-05-14#6449618a-f819-4d71-83ad-a1e4c2fe9bc1
```

Keep in mind there are hundreds of these files in a folder, I am trying to make them neater :)

What I got so far..

```
for file in os.listdir(src_path):
    if not os.path.isdir(dest_path + file.split("-")[:11]):
       os.mkdir(dest_path + file.split("-")[0])
shutil.copy(src_path + file, dest_path + file.split("-")[:11])
```

My thoughts were to match the first 11 digits..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to extract this:

`2015-05-14#7449618a-f819-4d71-83ad-a1e4c2fe9bc1`

You could grab the folder name you want much easier by simply splitting on the dot using `splitext` from `os.path`:

```
fname, fext = os.path.splitext('2015-05-14#6449618a-f819-4d71-83ad-a1e4c2fe9bc1.csv')
```

fname will hold `2015-05-14#7449618a-f819-4d71-83ad-a1e4c2fe9bc1`
fext will hold `csv`

Extra bit of information. Refrain from using `file`, it is a built-in for Python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file

It could lead to problems. Try `fname` or simply `f`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you would be better off running with:

```
file.rsplit(".",1)[0]
```

which would give you the path name to use for your directory.
The reason for using `rsplit` rather than `split` is just in case your files names have more than one full-stop in them
Note that you could achieve the same result with:

```
file.rpartition(".")[0]
```